# Occasional SEG FAULT when ofstream goes out of scope

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ofstream

I seldom have a seg fault issue when the std::ofstream is going out of scope. I have the following structs in my Logger.h:

```
        struct LogRequest
        {
            std::string line;
            std::string prefix;
        };

        struct FileInfo
        {
            std::string name;
            std::ofstream ofs;
            int lines;
            std::string ToString()
            {
                return (name + " exists");
        };
```

And in Logger.cpp, I have following functions:

```
void Logger::Log(const std::string line, std::string prefix)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (file_map.find(prefix) == file_map.end())
        {
            OpenLogFile(prefix);
        }

        LogRequest* request = new LogRequest;
        request->line = line;
        request->prefix = prefix;
        message_queue.push_back(request);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void Logger::OpenLogFile(const std::string& prefix)
{
    //get timestamp to use
    char timestamp[15];
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    struct tm* current = localtime(&now);
    sprintf(timestamp, "%02u%02u%04u_%02u%02u%02u", (current->tm_mon+1),
        current->tm_mday,(1900 + current->tm_year), current->tm_hour,
        current->tm_min, current->tm_sec);

    FileInfo* info = new FileInfo;
    info->name = "logs/" + prefix + ".log_" + timestamp;
    info->ofs.open(info->name.c_str(), std::ios::out);
    info->lines = 0;

    file_map[prefix] = info;
}

void Logger::CloseLogFile(const std::string& prefix)
{
    delete file_map[prefix];
}
```

And in a thread in Logger.cpp, I have...

```
void Logger::WriteToFile()
{
    std::map<std::string, FileInfo* >::iterator it;

    while(run)
    {
        char timestamp[16];
        time_t now;
        time(&now);
        struct tm* current = localtime(&now);
        sprintf(timestamp, "%02u%02u%04u|%02u%02u%02u|", (current->tm_mon+1),
            current->tm_mday,(1900 + current->tm_year), current->tm_hour,
            current->tm_min, current->tm_sec);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            for(it=file_map.begin(); it != file_map.end(); ++it)
            {
                if(it->second->lines > MAX_LINES)
                {
                    CloseLogFile(it->first);
                    OpenLogFile(it->first);
                }
                else
                {
                    int written = 0;

                    while(!message_queue.empty() && written < MESSAGES_PER_WRITE)
                    {
                        LogRequest* request = message_queue.front();
                        message_queue.pop_front();

                        std::string line(timestamp, 16);
                        line.append(request->line);

                        FileInfo* info = file_map[request->prefix];
                        info->ofs << line << std::endl;
                        info->lines++;
                        written++;
                        delete request;
                    }
                }
            }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        usleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that SOMETIMES there is a seg fault that gets thrown in the destructor of std::ofstream ofs in FileInfo when I try to `CloseLogFile`. It works many times. And even before the SEG Fault occurs (through various cout statements) I have confirmed that the std::ofstream is good, has not failed, not reached eof, and is not bad. I have also confirmed that file_map[prefix] exists, and is present by outputting FileInfo's ToString() as well. These are all checked right before deletion in CloseLogFile.

My question concerns the reason for the SEG FAULT.

Also when the line gets outputted to the ofstream in WriteToFile(), is it fine if I delete the LogRequest object. As in, what exactly is happening in the `info->ofs << line << std::endl;` line?

Comment: Double delete? You are not taking the entries out of the file_map, so it's possible that you close the file and than either close it again, which would cause the destructor or deallocator to crash, or writing to it and because the entry is still there, it wouldn't reopen and crash on write, because the buffer is not there anymore.

Comment: @JanHudec If you see in WriteToFile, I open up the new logfile immediately inside the mutex. Would a double delete still occur? And how I would I be able to see the ToString print statement beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your sprintf(timestamp...) call overwrites by one character (the null) which will cause undefined behavior.  may or may not be your primary issue though since that's on a thread stack and your ofs is on the heap...

Comment: Where is the null being written? Does sprintf add one in even if I do not write in \n?

Comment: Wow, that might be it... Idk how I missed that. That would explain why it was only occasionally seg fault, because the byte after timestamp is mostly always the null char, and occasionally getting overwritten. Do you know if there is a way to check if it is the solution? I don't know how to test it without just running it for a while and if it works, assuming it is fixed.

Comment: hard to prove the lack of a problem... if you're on linux, you might consider running it through valgrind if you've ever used that.  good tool for finding such things...

Comment: I have not seen the issue in quite some time now. Thank you for your help. I am quite sure it had to do with that.